# how to declare warning, error and fatalError function for DIxml?

Tags: xml, delphi, sax, delphi-2009

I am using DIxml to parse a couple of XML files. So far it worked great. Yesterday I got an XML file which seems to be correct, but cannot be parsed by DIxml. I do not yet have warning, error and fatalerror function implemented because it perfectly worked from day one :-)

I tried to implement these functions today but I get a compiler error from Delphi saying that my declaration differs from expected declaration. From my point of view, I did it right, but I am sure the compiler knows better.

I implemented the structuredError method like shown in the SAX2 example but my source never hits this function. All my hope now is on the fatal error method.

Here are some additional details regarding the function.

As the library is closed source, I do not have access to the correct declaration in the pas file. I only see the hoover/tooltip information when focusing the Warning method with my mouse.

first: How I initialize the SAX reader (part of it)

```
var
  f8      : Utf8String;
  User    : TImportData;
begin
  User := TImportData.Create;

  xmlInitParser; // Initialize the XML library.

  { Initialize the SAX2 handler. To start off with, we set all functions to
    nil. If we use a nil SAX parser like this, then we will have a parser that
    only checks that the document is well formed. }
  FillChar(FSaxHandler, SizeOf(FSaxHandler), 0);

  { By adding a few callbacks to the SAX handler, we can get the parser 
    to do just about anything. }
  FSaxHandler.startDocument   := SaxStartDocument;
  FSaxHandler.endDocument     := SaxEndDocument;
  FSaxHandler.characters      := SaxCharacters;
  FSaxHandler.Warning         := Warning;
  FSaxHandler.Error           := Error;
  FSaxHandler.fatalError      := fatalError;

end;

procedure SaxStartDocument(Ctx: Pointer);
var
  User: PImportData;
begin
  User                  := Ctx;

  //Do something with user...
end;

procedure Warning(Ctx: Pointer; Msg: PAnsiChar);
var
  User: PImportData;
begin
  User := Ctx;

  //Do something with user...
end;

procedure SaxCharacters(Ctx: Pointer; const Ch: xmlCharPtr; Len: Integer);
var
  s: Utf8String;
var
  User: PImportData;
begin
  User := Ctx;

  //Do something with user...
end;
```

When focusing the line `FSaxHandler.characters := Warning;` with the mouse, I get the following information in kind of tooltip window:

> Deklariert in DIXml.xmlSAXHandler
>
> ```
>  Parameters
>    Ctx 
>      System.Pointer 
>    Msg 
>      System.PAnsiChar
> ```

When focusing the line `FSaxHandler.characters := SaxCharacters;` I get the following tooltip

> characters Event 
>        Deklariert in DIXml.xmlSAXHandler
>
> ```
>  Parameters
>  Ctx 
>   System.Pointer 
>  Ch 
>   System.PAnsiChar 
>  Len 
>   System.Integer
> ```

When I the hit CTRL + F9 to compile the source, I get the following error message:

> [DCC Fehler] UnitSAX2_XML_Reader.pas(247): E2009 Inkompatible Typen: 'Unterschiede in der Aufrufkonvention'
>
> [DCC Fataler Fehler] importObjects.pas(8): F2063 Verwendete Unit 'UnitSAX2_XML_Reader.pas' kann nicht compiliert werden

Which means translated

> [DCC Error] UnitSAX2_XML_Reader.pas(247): E2009 Incompatible typs: 'differences  in Call definition'
>
> [DCC Fatal Error] importObjects.pas(8): F2063 used Unit 'UnitSAX2_XML_Reader.pas' can not be compiled

Comment: Show your method firm and show the type declaration the compiler expect it match. Without that bits, your question is very incomplete.

Comment: If you don't show us the original declaration and your declaration, it's very hard to help you identify the problem other than to say you should fix your declaration so it matches what the compiler expects. :-) Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14717464/edit) to provide those details, so we can help you.

Comment: Most common error here is of object mismatch. But since you didn't show any code, we cannot help.

Comment: Also, show the (relevant part of the) XML file.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there is some one who is already working with DIXML and can just post the three functions.

The warning function is declared as:
`**Parameters**
CTX
   System.Pointer
Msg
   System.PAnsiChar
`

An when I declare a function like this:
`procedure WarningEvent(CTX: Pointer; Msg: PAnsiChar)`

The compiler shouts on me

Comment: I can not post the XML file. It is 280MB big. And I do not know what is wrong with it. Obviously there is nothing wrong with file because the SAX2 Demo of DIXML parses it without any trace of an error.

Comment: For heaven's sake, put it all in the question. How do you expect us to read that cryptic comment. Put it in the question and format it properly. Put both pieces of information. The procedural type definitions from the library, and your attempts to match them. And don't say "the compiler shouts at me". Tell us exactly what it says. Use copy/paste.

Comment: I added some more details to the question.

Comment: Thank you. That's much better. Were are still missing the type definition for the three procedural types of the `FSaxHandler.Warning`, `FSaxHandler.Error` and `FSaxHandler.FatalError` events. We need those too.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the type definition. I only can see those tooltips when going with the mouse over it. 
I do not have access to the source code of the library.

Comment: Aufrufkonvention may refer not to the function firm but to the call convention used to invoke the function (which is part of it's definition). You really have to resort to documentation and not taking this as a guesswork. Anyway, if the library follows the Windows conventions, the function may be stdcall, or cdecl if it goes _a la c_.

Comment: Surely you have the unit in which the class is defined. And if not, and since you did not tell us what it is, how can we help?

Comment: There is no documentation, nor is this topic covered by the demos.

Comment: And as i said there is no source available. It was shipped as dcu. @david what else do you need me to tell you? I told you that it is the dixml sax2 parser. Today i recognized that there is a support mailing list. Hopefully i get the hint there. I will let you know. Thanks for everybody being so engaged so far.

Comment: OK, shipped as dcu. Fair enough. My advice to you is always to get components with source. Always. Anyway, surely the tooltip shows the declaration of the type. If you can include it here we can finish it off.

Comment: Yes, now I know that I would never again get something without source. The Tooltip shows just two parameters: 'Ctx System.Pointer' and 'Msg System.PAnsiChar'. Of course I tried a function with exactly theese, but it did not work. Meanwhile I got feedback from the mailing list. They told me to not use warning, error and fatal error method. There is a so called structured error message method wihcih works much better. I started using that one. (This one was covered by a demo shipped with the dcu) thanks for you help... cheers